# PHP Scope Resolution Operator Yields Undefined Class Constant

Tags: php, class, oop

I'm trying to use PHP's scope resolution operator to access the bar() method without instantiating the Foo class:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    public function bar()
    {
      return 'bar';
    }
}

echo Foo::bar;
```

But I'm getting:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'bar'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't 'access' methods, you can only call them. Also, the method should be marked static:

```php
<?php
class Foo {

    static function bar() {
      return 'bar';
    }

}

echo Foo::bar();
```

Comment: I ran your code and get: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'bar'

Comment: Did you run *everything*, or just the class part?

Comment: Never mind, it does work. The key was adding the "static" keyword. Awesome, thank you!